# Increase the prod_price during querying process

Tags: django

I have such a table of product with fields of prod_id, prod_name, prod_price...

```
MySQL [distributor]> select * from products;
+---------+---------+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| prod_id | vend_id | prod_name           | prod_price | prod_desc                                                             |
+---------+---------+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| BNBG01  | DLL01   | Fish bean bag toy   |       3.49 | Fish bean bag toy, complete with bean bag worms with which to feed it |
| BNBG02  | DLL01   | Bird bean bag toy   |       3.49 | Bird bean bag toy, eggs are not included                              |
| BNBG03  | DLL01   | Rabbit bean bag toy |       3.49 | Rabbit bean bag toy, comes with bean bag carrots                      |
| BR01    | BRS01   | 8 inch teddy bear   |       5.99 | 8 inch teddy bear, comes with cap and jacket                          |
| BR02    | BRS01   | 12 inch teddy bear  |       8.99 | 12 inch teddy bear, comes with cap and jacket                         |
| BR03    | BRS01   | 18 inch teddy bear  |      11.99 | 18 inch teddy bear, comes with cap and jacket                         |
| RGAN01  | DLL01   | Raggedy Ann         |       4.99 | 18 inch Raggedy Ann doll                                              |
| RYL01   | FNG01   | King doll           |       9.49 | 12 inch king doll with royal garments and crown                       |
| RYL02   | FNG01   | Queen doll          |       9.49 | 12 inch queen doll with royal garments and crown                      |
+---------+---------+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.019 sec)
```

The prod_price could be update by:

```
MySQL [distributor]> update products
    -> set prod_price = prod_price + 1;
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.038 sec)
Rows matched: 9  Changed: 9  Warnings: 0

MySQL [distributor]> select * from products;
+---------+---------+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| prod_id | vend_id | prod_name           | prod_price | prod_desc                                                             |
+---------+---------+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| BNBG01  | DLL01   | Fish bean bag toy   |       4.49 | Fish bean bag toy, complete with bean bag worms with which to feed it |
| BNBG02  | DLL01   | Bird bean bag toy   |       4.49 | Bird bean bag toy, eggs are not included                              |
| BNBG03  | DLL01   | Rabbit bean bag toy |       4.49 | Rabbit bean bag toy, comes with bean bag carrots                      |
| BR01    | BRS01   | 8 inch teddy bear   |       6.99 | 8 inch teddy bear, comes with cap and jacket                          |
| BR02    | BRS01   | 12 inch teddy bear  |       9.99 | 12 inch teddy bear, comes with cap and jacket                         |
| BR03    | BRS01   | 18 inch teddy bear  |      12.99 | 18 inch teddy bear, comes with cap and jacket                         |
| RGAN01  | DLL01   | Raggedy Ann         |       5.99 | 18 inch Raggedy Ann doll                                              |
| RYL01   | FNG01   | King doll           |      10.49 | 12 inch king doll with royal garments and crown                       |
| RYL02   | FNG01   | Queen doll          |      10.49 | 12 inch queen doll with royal garments and crown                      |
+---------+---------+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

If in Django, I should retrieve the Product query-set firstly then to increase the price individually using for loop and save them back to the database finally.

How could I update the prod_price with Django ORM as it was manipulated with raw SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use F model

```
from django.db.models import F
Product.objects.filter(pk__in=ids).update(prod_price=F('prod_price')+1)
```